# Unable to render data in my view for my express app

Tags: javascript, express, ejs, bookshelf.js

I am attempting to get data returned from a database rendered in my web page, but have been unable to do so. I am using using ejs as my templating engine, bookshelf(orm) and express as my node framework.

My model looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var bookshelf = require('../bookshelf');

var Contact = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'contacts',
});

module.exports = Contact;
```

My controller looks like this:

```
function list(req, res, next) {
  new Contact().fetchAll()
    .then(function(contacts) {
      var contacts = contacts.toJSON();
      var contacts = JSON.stringify(contacts);
       console.log(contacts)
      res.render('contacts', {
        contacts: contacts
      });
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.send('An error occured');
    })
}
```

And my template looks like this:

```
<% include partials/header %>
      <h1><%= test %></h1>
      <ul>
        <% contacts.forEach(function(contacts){ %>
          <li><%= contacts.firstName%></li>
        <% }) %>
      </ul>
<% include partials/footer %>
```

What I wish to happen is for that for each contact their first name shold be displayed on the page. However nothing is displayed even though the console.log statement (in the controller) displays this in the console:

```
[{"id":1,"firstName":"tom","lastName":"jones","emailAddress":"joney@test.com"},{"id":2,"firstName":"don","lastName":"jon","emailAddress":"don@test.com"}]
```

So data is returned from the DB, just not rendered in my view. Can anybody help me out with what I am doing wrong?

Method 2:

Below is a new way I have tried to do this. However this just results in the JSON been displayed on my web page.

```
function list(req, res) {
Contact.fetchAll()
    .then(contacts => res.json({
          contacts
        })
    ).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
      res.send('An error occured');
    })
}
```

Comment: You should rename your `contacts` variable in the `forEach` handler to make it less ambiguous. It's just a single contact, so `contact` would be a good name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that bookshelf orm return a [collection](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection) object, and you can use `.toArray()` method to transform it to an array and then pass it to your view without calling `JSON.stringify`, Try this:

```
function list(req, res, next) {
    new Contact().fetchAll()
        .then(function(contacts) {
            res.render('contacts', {
                contacts: contacts.toArray()
            });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.send('An error occured');
        });
}
```

Comment: Hi YouneL, thanks for your response. That did not work unfortunately. However as a test rather that pass the bookshelf collection object to my controller I passed some sample json and it rendered on the page fine. So it is something to do with the object returned by bookshelf. I will keep digging and see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be double `toJSON()`-ing your contacts collection. There is no need to call `toJSON()` explicitly if you're going to call `JSON.stringify()` afterwards, since that method already calls `.toJSON()` on its own.

However, that's not the problem here. The real problem is that you're stringifying the collection, meaning it's a string when used on the template, so it's not possible to treat it like an object.

If you just remove the `JSON.stringify(contacts);` part it should work fine.

Comment: Hi Devius, unfortunately that did not work, does not seem to be able to render the page with the contents, see this in the terminal: `GET /contacts 500 10.040 ms -`. I have added a new method(see method 2 in the original question), but this just results in JSON getting displayed on the page.

Comment: I never used *ejs* personally, but what I suggested works just fine with *handlebars*. If you call `res.json()` it will render the output as JSON only, so that's what you're getting in that case. Are you sure the `contacts` variable is available in the view? What happens when you just output it directly without any loop?

Comment: Also, if you're getting a 500 error most likely it means there's a problem with your code somewhere. What's the actual error you're getting? There must be something printed on the console.